# Change hover function to click on small screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some text content that appears on the hover of the image. But in the mobile version, I need it to change to a click to open function.

```
<div class="program prog-image" style="background-image: url(https://imagevars.gulfnews.com/2019/07/23/Timberwolf_16c1de35555_base.jpg)">
      <div class="more-details"> 
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, voluptates.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

<style>
    .program{
        height: 400px;
        width: 700px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .more-details{
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    ul{
        list-style: none;
    }
    .program:hover .more-details{
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
```

I mean I want it to look like an accordion with arrows. Anyone can help?

Comment: Need to add jquery mobile click.. Is that ok for u?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 it is all fine for me to add jquery. I'm a bit backward on that

Comment: ok 15mins i will send the jquery code..

Comment: Just show it both on hover and click, no need to add any more libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:focus`. Make sure that element with `.program` class supports `:focus` pseudo class.
You may need to use `<a>` tag instead of `<div>`. Not sure if `<div>` has `:focus` state.

```
    .program:hover .more-details,
    .program:focus .more-details {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Or you can use js

```
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".program");

  elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      el.classList.toggle('open')
    })
  })
```

And modify you styles a bit

```
    .program:hover .more-details,
    .program.open .more-details {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I actually need it to click to show and on the next click on the same item it should hide. Like accordion

Comment: I've update the answer. Hope it solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript i think . It's my solve :

```js
const temp = document.querySelector(".prog-image");
const details = document.querySelector(".more-details");
const showText = () =>{
 console.log("W"); details.classList.toggle("detail");
}
temp.addEventListener("click",showText);
temp.addEventListener("mouseover",showText);
temp.addEventListener("mouseout",showText);
```

```html
<div class="program prog-image" style="background-image: url(https://imagevars.gulfnews.com/2019/07/23/Timberwolf_16c1de35555_base.jpg)">
      <div class="more-details"> 
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, voluptates.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
  .detail{
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: It is showing when I click. But it is not hiding if I click again.

Answer (score 0):

Plz follow the above code..

**HTML**

```
<div class="program">
 <div class="prog-image" style="background-image: url(https://imagevars.gulfnews.com/2019/07/23/Timberwolf_16c1de35555_base.jpg)">
  <div class="more-details">
   <ul>
     <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, voluptates.</li>
     <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.program{
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
}
.prog-image {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.more-details {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .more-details{
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .program:hover .more-details{
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .program{
      width: 100%;
    }
    .prog-image.content-show .more-details {
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**JQuery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.prog-image').click(function() {
          jQuery(this).toggleClass("content-show");
        });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery to your code:

```
$(".program").click(function () {
    $(".more-details").css("opacity", 1);
    });
```